# Parse Image Save Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm new to coding in general and have built a photo section app based on apple and parse code.

Despite a number of attempts to tweak the code I cannot get the image to save to my parse dashboard. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

The code I am using is this:

```
- (IBAction)showImagePickerForPhotoPicker:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Code shows image picker for album in APLViewController.m");
[self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
```

......

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToUse;

// Handle a still image picked from a photo album
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (editedImage) {
        imageToUse = editedImage;
    } else {
        imageToUse = originalImage;

    }
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"Code reached parse save code");
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (originalImage);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];

    PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
    userPhoto[@"imageName"] = @"My trip to Hawaii!";
    userPhoto[@"imageFile"] = imageFile;
    [userPhoto saveInBackground];
    NSLog(@"code reaches addobject to captured images array");
    [self.capturedImages addObject:image];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(640, 960));
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960)];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the saveing process needs to be outside the imagePicker. It should look something like this. And should run when everything is around picking the image is done.

```
        PFUser *profile = [PFUser currentUser];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image, 0.8);
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", profile.username];
        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
       [profile setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profileimageFile"];
       [profile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Show success message
            }
            else {
                // Show error message
            }       
        }];
```

To save the profile image you need to first **select where** you want to save the image. In this case is at the currentUser. Then you **convert** the image that you picked in to a NSData file. Then you need to give that datafile a name. Then out of that you **create a PFFile**. And then you save that file to parse.

Geting the Image back is kind of the same but backwards:

```
PFFile *userImageFile = [PFUser currentUser][@"profileImageFile"];
[userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }        
}];
```